# MAC OS X hotkeys with Java applications unfocused...is it possible?

Tags: java, macos, hotkeys

As Stephan asked 2 years ago...
A Java6 application sits in the system tray / dock. It needs to be activated using a hotkey (e.g. Super-G or Ctrl-Shift-L etc) and do something (e.g. showing an input box).

I found the answer for Windows and Linux.

But what about MAC OS X? Is it doable?

Comment: Didn't this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6422079/1356559 work for MAC OSX ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://bitbucket.org/agynamix/ossupport-connector. It claimed to be "a cross platform global hotkey library for Java". (Never worked with it before).