# I need global keyboard listener in java for Mac

Tags: java, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-hook

I know that you can listen for keyboard with JIntellitype in Windows but is there something similar for Mac? Thank.

Comment: Maybe this post can give you an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79658/react-on-global-hotkey-in-a-java-program-on-windows-linux-mac

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

JNativeHook doesn't register global shortcuts directly but you should be able to accomplish the same thing with a global keyboard listener.  Supports Windows Linux and OS X.

http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

From the other thread pointed out by Byron Voorbach:  https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster (Requires JNA)