# What are my options with addKeyListener

Tags: java, swing, addition, keylistener

I want to add a KeyListener and have it only be attached to the program itself so that my program can take input without having any sort of window. I would like to have it run in the backround and change some of the functions of the keys. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. A KeyListener needs to run in a Swing/AWT program. This program requires a container ("window")

Comment: are you sure there is no way around? should i use something different then a keylistener?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Do you mean you want the listener to be registered to a non GUI program?

Comment: i want to have a java program running that adds function to the keyboard. I dont want it to be visible and i dont want it to ever lose focus, so that the added functions will work as long as the program is running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React on global hotkey in a Java program on Windows/Linux/Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79658/react-on-global-hotkey-in-a-java-program-on-windows-linux-mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. I think you want to use key bindings and not a KeyListener. See the code beloww. I've binded the four arrow keys to different actions. Take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeyBindings extends JPanel {
    public KeyBindings(){
        Action upAction = new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Down Arrow Pressed");
            }
        };
        Action downAction = new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Down Arrow Pressed");
            }
        };
        Action leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Left Arrow Pressed");
            }
        };
        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Right Arrow Pressed");
            }
        };


        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upAction");
        getActionMap().put("upAction", upAction);
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "downAction");
        getActionMap().put("downAction", downAction);
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
        getActionMap().put("leftAction", leftAction);
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
        getActionMap().put("rightAction", rightAction);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new KeyBindings());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your App a Service which will run in the background automatically, click [here for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)