# How to make key combinations without a window

Tags: java, javafx

So I want to for example press CTRL + Alt + D and something happens. And that without a window from javafx (which I use). So then I can press this key combination everytime (if my application is on).
Is that possible? If yes how would I do that?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79658/react-on-global-hotkey-in-a-java-program-on-windows-linux-mac *Spoiler* you need JNI.

Comment: thanks I will try that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React on global hotkey in a Java program on Windows/Linux/Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79658/react-on-global-hotkey-in-a-java-program-on-windows-linux-mac)

Comment: yes that worked

Comment: but if I want to change anything from javafx I need Platform.runLater and that is only called one time (if I press once its working but the second time nothing happens)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your primaryStage scene something like this:

```
primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    KeyCombination combination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.D,KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN,KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN);
    if (combination.match(keyEvent)) {
        System.out.println("Ctrl+Alt+D was pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work outside of the window